# Re-naming bulk images using "time taken"

Tags: python, vba, image, sorting

I'm working in a project which will require me to organise and sort 1000's of images of distribution boards (DB) - there will be 10-15 images per DB. To automate the process I want to rename the images in blocks using the time created.

For instance all images of a particular DB will be taken within 30 seconds of another, any time longer than that will constitute a different DB and therefore a different "block" of images.

Initially, i was thinking of writing a VBA script creating all individual folders with each DB's individual name and then dumping all relevant images in set folder. And then using a python script to rename the images inside each folder to ie. DBXXXX_1, 2, 3, etc., however there is still a lot of mucking around with this solution.

Would anyone be able to suggest a more elegant solution? ie. is it possible to distinguish between blocks of images (t>30s = new block) using python or VBA code and then be prompted to input the name of the DB, and sort it to an individual folder?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow Q&A format doesn't work with open/opiniated design discussions; please take a moment to enjoy the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: you could use excel to make a list of image filenames and creation time. i would get filenames and creation time using a batch file. or even do it manually by setting the cmd window buffer to 9999 lines, do `dir /s *.jpg` or whatever format the pictures are, then copy and paste into excel .... takes like 2 minutes and no code has to be written to do the import

Comment: then process the list in excel (copy oldfilename to newfilename with intervening directory creations)

Answer (score 0):

Your task is not clear to me, so I decided to write 2 short snippets in `python` and `vba` to help you get started

This code will rename all files in `C:\` to `DBXXXX_1`...,

### VBA Code

```
Dim i as Integer, FileName as String, NewFileName as String
i = 1
FileName = Dir("C:\")
While FileName<>""
NewFileName = "DBXXXX_" & i
Name FileName as NewFileName
FileName = Dir()
i = i + 1
Wend
```

### Python code

```
import os
for i, filename in enumerate(os.listdir("C:/")):
    newfilename = "C:/DBXXXX_{i}".format(i=i)
    os.rename(filename, newfilename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but it should help you get started. You can use the `jhead` tool ([here](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/)) to rename an image, or a whole directory of images very simply.

For example, to rename a file called `iPhoneSample.jpg` so that its filename becomes the number of seconds since 1st Jan 1970 (the Unix epoch) when it was taken, you can do:

```
jhead -n%s iPhoneSample.jpg 
iPhoneSample.jpg --> 1362819590.jpg
```

which has renamed it to `1362819590.jpg`

you can see the date/time an image was taken with:

```
jhead iPhoneSample.jpg

File name    : iPhoneSample.jpg
File size    : 2219100 bytes
File date    : 2017:08:20 11:47:41
Camera make  : Apple
Camera model : iPhone 4
Date/Time    : 2013:03:09 08:59:50
Resolution   : 2592 x 1936
Flash used   : No
Focal length :  3.8mm  (35mm equivalent: 35mm)
Exposure time: 0.0011 s  (1/914)
Aperture     : f/2.8
ISO equiv.   : 80
Whitebalance : Auto
Metering Mode: pattern
Exposure     : program (auto)
GPS Latitude : N 20d 50.66m  0s
GPS Longitude: E 107d  5.46m  0s
GPS Altitude :  1.13m
JPEG Quality : 96
```

Please make a copy of a few sample files in a test directory away from your main image repository and try renaming all files like this:

```
jhead -n%s *.jpg
```

There are lots of other ways to rename files according to the time or their characteristics, I just used `%s` for seconds since 1970, if you want to see more look [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html).

---

I am guessing you are hobbled with Windows, but to give you an idea (or if you feel like installing Windows versions of `awk` and `sort`), under Linux/Unix you can get a directory listing and sort your filenames into time order like this:

```
ls | sort -n
```

You can then process that list with `awk` and update the block/group number when two times differ by more than 30 seconds like this:

```
ls | sort -n | awk -F'.' 'BEGIN{g=0}{if(($1-prev)>30){g++};print g,$1; prev=$1}'

1 1362295676
1 1362295677        <--- same group as before since images only 1 second apart
2 1362307049
3 1362330568
4 1362391436
5 1362392032
6 1362396147
7 1362399189
8 1362399675
9 1362404200
10 1362486924
11 1362496052
12 1362496675
13 1362569635
14 1362746526
15 1362747304
16 1362756678
17 1362756849
18 1362757004
18 1362757020
19 1362758801
20 1362766499
21 1362812455
22 1362812496
23 1362818636
24 1362819216
24 1362819233        <--- same group as before since images only 17 seconds apart
25 1362819590
26 1363015134
26 1363015136        <--- same group as before since images only 2 seconds apart
```